# Instagram basic display authentication has CORS error

Tags: cors, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I followed the following page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started#step-5--exchange-  the-code-for-a-token
Everything works fine until step 4. I have made sure every information in [https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={app-id}&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}&scope=user_profile&response_type=code](https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=%7Bapp-id%7D&redirect_uri=%7Bredirect-uri%7D&scope=user_profile&response_type=code) is correct. but after login I always get CORS error.I tried creating a test user, and when I clicked Generate Token. it still has the same error. Can Generate Token still have CORS errors? I need some help!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ycx9L.jpg)